# Filter in group_by + mutate not working as in group_by + summarise in dplyr R

Tags: r, dplyr

I am having problems **filtering** when **mutating** a dataframe using `tidyverse`:

```
sample.df <- data.frame(
  group = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "C"),
  value = c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
)

mutated.sample.df <- sample.df %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(group) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(group_count = n()) 

non.desired.df <- mutated.sample.df %>% 
  dplyr::filter(group_count == max(group_count)) %>% 
  dplyr::select(-group_count)
```

This returns a non desired solution as **no filter** has been applied:

```
 group value
  <fct> <dbl>
1 A         1
2 A         2
3 A         3
4 B         4
5 B         5
6 C         6
```

On the other hand, working directly with **summarizing** the filter is properly applied:

```
summarized.sample.df <- sample.df %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(group) %>% 
  dplyr::summarise(group_count = n()) %>% 
  dplyr::filter(group_count == max(group_count))
```

giving:

```
 group group_count
  <fct>       <int>
1 A               3
```

I could now filter the original dataframe and get my desired df:

```
desired.df <- sample.df %>% 
  dplyr::filter(group %in% summarized.sample.df$group)
```

That is:

```
  group value
  <fct> <dbl>
1 A         1
2 A         2
3 A         3
```

What am I missing in **mutating** behaviour? I can filter just "hard coding" the value:

```
my.max <- max(mutated.sample.df$group_count)
desired.df <- mutated.sample.df %>% 
  dplyr::filter(group_count == my.max) %>% 
  dplyr::select(-group_count)
```

Would it be possible to obtain the desired.df in one pipe? Both in summarizing and in mutating *hard* calculating the `max` I can not.

I would expect this to work, but it does not. Any hint why?

```
mutated.sample.df <- sample.df %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(group) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(group_count = n()) %>% 
  dplyr::filter(group_count == max(group_count)) %>% 
  dplyr::select(-group_count)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code from @tmfmnk is better, but your pipe isn't working because you forgot to "ungroup()" the dataframe between mutate and filter, so the "filter()" are working within the groups. Try:

```
mutated.sample.df <- sample.df %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(group) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(group_count = n()) %>% 
  dplyr::ungroup()  %>% 
  dplyr::filter(group_count == max(group_count)) %>% 
  dplyr::select(-group_count)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
sample.df %>%
 add_count(group) %>%
 filter(n == max(n)) %>%
 select(-n)

  group value
1     A     1
2     A     2
3     A     3
```